# Model Type error: Passing DbQuery instead of IGrouping

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Can anybody tell me how to resolve this error?

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery 1[Project.ViewModels.TestViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,Project.ViewModels.TestViewModel]]'.

**ViewModel**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NameCount {get; set; }
    public int NameSum { get; set; }
    public double NameAverage { get; set; }
}
```

**Action Method**

```
var groupedfListItems = db.FListItems.Include(f => f.FList)
                                     .Include(f => f.Item)
                                     .GroupBy(g => g.Item.Name)
                                     .Select(lg =>
                                     new TestViewModel
                                     { 
                                         Name = lg.Key, 
                                         NameCount = lg.Count(),
                                         NameSum = lg.Sum(w => w.Score), 
                                         NameAverage = lg.Average(w => w.Score)
                                      });
return View(groupedfListItems);
```

I've tried appending `AsEnumerable()` and `ToList()` without success.

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Project.ViewModels.TestViewModel>>

<table class="table">

@foreach (IGrouping<string, Project.ViewModels.TestViewModel> item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Key)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Count()
        </td>

        @foreach (var i in item)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.NameAverage)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.NameCount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.NameSum)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: What type do you see on `groupedfListItems`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the type expected on your view is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Project.ViewModels.TestViewModel>>` but the type you are passing is `IQueryable<TestViewModel>` the error is just pointing this out.

Try to change the View model to:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.TestViewModel>
```

or change the query on your code behind to:

```
var groupedfListItems = db.FListItems.Include(f => f.FList)
                                 .Include(f => f.Item)
                                 .Select(lg =>
                                 new TestViewModel
                                 { 
                                     Name = lg.Item.Key,
                                  })
                                 .GroupBy(g => g.Name);
```

in here update the counts inside the groups.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. Which option is preferable?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do, only you can decide.